# VueJS SPA app high memory usage when navigating to pages

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, memory-leaks, mobile-safari

VueJS SPA app high memory usage when navigating to pages

The whole thing started when some users on old phones started to report random crashes in ios (IP 6 - 7). According to safari’s dev profiler (Attaching screenshots), memory is consumed mostly by the “Page” category which according to them is “Engine memory related to the DOM, styles, rendering data, memory caches, system allocations, etc.”

1. Memory keeps rising as the user navigates.
2. App crashes where the user navigate between pages quickly, mostly in wizards as memory keeps accumulating.
3. The memory usage drop after a couple of seconds if the user stay on the same page without navigating (refer to screenshot).
   The most affected areas of the app are features where there are wizards involved.
   Questions I have
4. From where should I start to optimize? The resources there focus a lot on the JS side of thing not “Page”.
5. Can this be a common pitfall SPA app in general?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Useful link to VueJS documentation on avoiding memory leaks: https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Comment: Hi lan. I referred that doc but it didn't help

Comment: @SanjulaMadumalHewage Hope this issue has been resolved. Can you share the solution here?